# Django Orm , include function like asp.net core

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_year = models.IntegerField()
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField()
    daily_rate = models.FloatField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

i have this kind of model i want to query the data to become like this. how do i do it like this ???

```
[
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "123123",
    "release_year": 4,
    "number_in_stock": 12,
    "daily_rate": 1.234,
    "genre": {
      "genre_id": 4,
      "name": "Action"
    },
    "date_created": "2019-10-30T08:33:59.846Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the object.

There are a few ways to do this :

- using `model_to_dict`
- using json serializer

See : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/